# Difference between "#id li{...}" and "#id > li{...}"

Tags: css

I came across these two somewhat similar things. In one of my applications, there is a difference between these two, especially when using `IE7`. I wonder: what is the big difference between these two. Feel free to elaborate and site links.

Comment: In IE 7 or IE 8, in "Quirks" mode (and maybe "standards" of IE7, not sure) Child selectors are ignored.

Comment: Remember to [up vote and accept](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12520400/144665).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space selects *all* descendants. The `>` selects only *direct* descendants ("child" elements).

See [this w3 page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) for a great overview of all selectors. From that page:

> E > F ... an F element child of an E element ... [child combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)

And:

> E F ... an F element descendant of an E element ... [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

Note that this difference isn't particular to IE7. All decently modern browsers support both syntaxes. The same selectors also exist in [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching). On [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) I only see that IE6 and below (*shudder*) have issues with the child selector.

Answer (score 3):

This will apply to **all** `li` elements beneath the #id element

```
#id li
```

This will apply only to the `li` elements **directly** below the #id element

```
#id > li
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the standard `X Y` and `X > Y` is that the latter will only select direct children. For example, consider the following markup.

```
<div id="container">  
   <ul>  
      <li> List Item  
        <ul>  
           <li> Child </li>  
        </ul>  
      </li>  
      <li> List Item </li>  
      <li> List Item </li>  
      <li> List Item </li>  
   </ul>  
</div>
```

A selector of `#container > ul` will only target the uls which are direct children of the div with an id of container. It will not target, for instance, the ul that is a child of the first li.

For this reason, **there are performance benefits in using the child combinator**. In fact, it’s recommended particularly when working with JavaScript-based CSS selector engines.

Source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/